# Вывод тегов из бд

Tags: php, mysql

В базе хранятся теги разделенные пробелом, как их вывести, что бы они были по отдельности?
А потом, например, если в колонке есть 2 тега, искать тот который нужен, а не полной строкой?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка на уровне проектирования. Очевидно, что теги - сущность для которой нужна отдельная таблица.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в одной строке (записи) хранятся все теги? Тогда стандартными средствами PHP выбираете строку из базы и парсите:

```
explode(" ", $db_query);
```

Получите на выходе массив с тэгами.

Только не перепутайте порядок параметров для функции explode(). Об этой функции подробно написано [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php).

> а потом например если в колонке есть 2
> тега, искать тот который нужен, а не
> полной строкой?

Не понял, перефразируйте.

Comment: да все верно, если 2, искать тот который нужен?

Comment: Искать уже в php. Иначе -- разбивать строку тегов в запросе sql (разбиралось на stackoverflow.com)